# How to make preg_match_all find match if multi or single line?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this regex which works fine only if the strings are on multiline

```
#\[link.*?href\=\"(.*)?\".*?title\=\"(.*?)\".*?class\=\"(.*?)\".*?\](.*?)\[\/link\]#e
```

matches ok if second string is on new line

```
[link href="somehref" title="sometitle" class="someclas"]Text[/link]
[link href="somehref" title="sometitle" class="someclas"]Text2[/link]
```

matches last one partially if everything is on single line

```
[link href="somehref" title="sometitle" class="someclas"]Text[/link][link href="somehref" title="sometitle" class="someclas"]Text2[/link]
```

How do I make it match either, multi or single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was here `href\=\"(.*)` too greedy... replaced with `href\=\"(.*?)`

```
preg_match_all('%\[link.*?href="(.*?)?".*?title="(.*?)".*?class="(.*?)".*?\](.*?)\[\/link\]%i', $email, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

http://regex101.com/r/lG7sQ6

Comment: O boy! Great find, 4am here , cant see anything. Have about 10 of those to match. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Benn 3 am here... Happy to help ! have a good night...working ;)

Comment: The question mark wasn't *missing*, it was in the wrong place.  That is, `(.*)?` was supposed to be `(.*?)`.